# Moving Elements around in Date Field

Tags: theming, datetime

Trying to make the [Date](https://www.drupal.org/project/date) Module a little more user friendly.

I found out how to remove the Fieldset wrapper, and put the start and end dates in line, but due to where the check box resides, the field is a little too high, and does not sit well with the rest of the fields around it:

[image: Normal Date Layout]

Would be great if I could get that check box up in the label like below:

[image: Date checkbox in label]

Or inline like this option:

[image: Date checkbox inline]

I'm a bit of a hack, and my efforts playing with CSS have come up with nothing (relative/absolute positioning on the checkbox works in a way, but it's really untidy and awful for a responsive site). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

To help, here's the additional template.php code to remove the fieldset:

```
function stability_date_combo($variables) {
  return theme('form_element', $variables);
}
```

And here's the replacement CSS to get the elements working in line:

```
/* Force from/to dates to float using inline-block, where it works, otherwise inline. */
.container-inline-date {
  width:auto;
  clear:both;
  display: inline-block; /*change to inline block */
  *display: inline;
  vertical-align:top;
  margin-right: 0.5em; /* LTR */
}
.container-inline-date .form-item {
  float:none;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
.container-inline-date .form-item .form-item {
  float: left; /* LTR */
}
.container-inline-date .form-item,
.container-inline-date .form-item input {
  width:auto;
}
.container-inline-date .description {
  clear: both;
}

.container-inline-date .form-item input,
.container-inline-date .form-item select,
.container-inline-date .form-item option {
  margin-right: 5px; /* LTR */
}

.container-inline-date .date-spacer {
  margin-left: -5px; /* LTR */
}
.views-right-60 .container-inline-date div {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}

.container-inline-date .date-timezone .form-item {
  float:none;
  width:auto;
  clear:both;
}

/* Fixes for date popup css so it will behave in Drupal */
#calendar_div, #calendar_div td, #calendar_div th {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#calendar_div,
.calendar_control,
.calendar_links,
.calendar_header,
.calendar {
  width: 185px;
  border-collapse: separate;
  margin: 0;
}
.calendar td {
  padding: 0;
}

/* formatting for from/to dates in nodes and views */
span.date-display-single {
}
span.date-display-start {
}
span.date-display-end {
}
span.date-display-separator {
}

.date-repeat-input {
  float: left; /* LTR */
  width:auto;
  margin-right: 5px; /* LTR */
}
.date-repeat-input select {
  min-width:7em;
}
.date-repeat fieldset {
  clear:both;
  float:none;
}

.date-views-filter-wrapper {
  min-width:250px;
}
.date-views-filter input {
  float: left !important; /* LTR */
  margin-right: 2px !important; /* LTR */
  padding:0 !important;
  width:12em;
  min-width:12em;
}
/* Give the navigation bar a little extra padding below so it will clear the new contextual links overlay of the teasers below it. */
.date-nav {
  width:100%;
  padding-bottom:1.5em;
  clear: both;
}
.date-nav div.date-prev {
  text-align: left; /* LTR */
  width:24%;
  float: left; /* LTR */
}
.date-nav div.date-next {
  text-align: right; /* LTR */
  width:24%;
  float: right; /* LTR */
}
.date-nav div.date-heading {
  text-align:center;
  width:50%;
  float: left; /* LTR */
}
.date-nav div.date-heading h3 {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.date-clear {
  float:none;
  clear:both;
  display:block;
}

.date-clear-block {
  float:none;
  width:auto;
  clear:both;
}

/*   
 ** Markup free clearing that fixes unwanted scrollbars      
 ** @see http://drupal.org/node/232959   
 */      
 .date-clear-block:after {   
   content: " ";     
   display: block;   
   height: 0;    
   clear: both;      
   visibility: hidden;   
 }   
 .date-clear-block {     
   display: inline-block;    
 }   
 /* Hides from IE-mac \*/    
 * html .date-clear-block {      
   height: 1%;   
 }   
 .date-clear-block {     
   display: block;   
 }   
 /* End hide from IE-mac */

.date-container .date-format-delete {
  margin-top: 1.8em;
  margin-left: 1.5em;
  float: left;
}
.date-container .date-format-name {
  float: left;
}
.date-container .date-format-type {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.date-container .select-container {
  clear: left;
  float: left;
}

/* Calendar day css */
div.date-calendar-day {
  line-height: 1;
  width: 40px;
  float: left;
  margin: 6px 10px 0 0;
  background: #F3F3F3;
  border-top: 1px solid #eee;
  border-left: 1px solid #eee;
  border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
  color: #999;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Georgia, Arial, Verdana, sans;
}
div.date-calendar-day span {
  display: block;  
  text-align: center;
}
div.date-calendar-day span.month {
  font-size: .9em;
  background-color: #B5BEBE;
  color: white;
  padding: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
div.date-calendar-day span.day {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
}
div.date-calendar-day span.year {
  font-size: .9em;
  padding: 2px;
}

/* Remove 'TO:' label, as it creates a taller block and throws out placement'  */

label[for*='-field-engagement-duration'][for*='-und-0-value2']{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: This is definitely a job for CSS, can you add the code you have so far? Or give us URL to see the form?

Comment: Thanks @Collins, I'm running off a local server, so can't provide a link, but I have updated the post with the existing CSS I'm using and additional template.php code to get it like the first image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So kids, no one could help me on this one, but if you want to do something similar, I was able to figure out the inline option...

It's not exactly how pictured, but you'll need to change the weight of the checkbox to 4.1 - this can be found on line 309 of date_elements.inc (it's currently set to -20)

I also changed "Show End Date" to be just "To:", rather than hiding the label after the checkbox is ticked (although I'm sure I could work that out too)

You'll have to tweak some CSS in date.css to get other things working and lining up nicely too.

End result:

[image]

EDIT: Dute to some module updates, line 315 (old 309) needs to be changed from -20 to something like 6, and line 382 (the from field) needs to be updated from .2 to something like 5